# Jquery Ajax Loading image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to implement a loading image for my jquery ajax code (this is when the jquery is still processing) below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "newarticlescallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) { 
        alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }   
});
```

How can I implement a loading image in this code.
Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="LoadingImage" style="display: none">
  <img src="" />
</div>

<script>
  function ajaxCall(){
    $("#LoadingImage").show();
      $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: surl, 
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        cache : false, 
        jsonp : "onJSONPLoad", 
        jsonpCallback: "newarticlescallback", 
        crossDomain: "true", 
        success: function(response) { 
          $("#LoadingImage").hide();
          alert("Success"); 
        }, 
        error: function (xhr, status) {  
          $("#LoadingImage").hide();
          alert('Unknown error ' + status); 
        }    
      });  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add some indentation? This makes blood come out of my eyes :P

Comment: Instead of repeating your self with the code  
$.("#LoadingImage").hide(); in both "success" and "error" functions, use the "complete" function of the Ajax options.

Comment: used the concept with jquery .load()  .. thnx

Answer (score 55):

#### Description

You should do this using `jQuery.ajaxStart` and `jQuery.ajaxStop`.

1. Create a div with your image
2. Make it visible in `jQuery.ajaxStart`
3. Hide it in `jQuery.ajaxStop`

#### Sample

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none">Your Image</div>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var loading = $("#loading");
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            loading.show();
        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            loading.hide();
        });

        $("#startAjaxRequest").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.google.com",
                // ... 
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="startAjaxRequest">Start</button>
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)
- [jQuery.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

Comment: So with this approach, on every ajax request image is shown. What if I do not want to. If you want to execute some ajax requests silently without informing the user.

Comment: How is it not SEO friendly? (Honest Question)

Comment: ajaxStart will be called only for first ajax request. This will not be called when any other ajax request is in progress.

Comment: @svlada, you can disable ajax global events for some ajax request, just setting global to false in this ajax request options.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit late but if you don't want to use a div specifically, I usually do it like this...

```
var ajax_image = "<img src='/images/Loading.gif' alt='Loading...' />";
$('#ReplaceDiv').html(ajax_image);
```

ReplaceDiv is the div that the Ajax inserts too. So when it arrives, the image is replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that:
ajaxStart / ajaxStop is not working for ajax jsonp request (ajax json request is ok)

I am using jquery 1.7.2 while writing this.

here is one of the reference I found:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8338