# Detect end of ajax request from asp by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

If the user click on an `input`-tag (`type="radio"`), I load new data from the database. Because it can spend a time, I show a loading animation. After it must the animation be undisplayed.

Now is my question: how can I detect if your ajax request from an aspx page has been finished by javascript code for undisplaying the animation? If no, are there other ways to get the same result?

**Update 1:** I use only this lines of code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true"  runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlCategorieen" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlHoofdTopics" CssClass="topics" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCategorien" CssClass="topics" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlItems" CssClass="topics" runat="server" />

        <asp:Panel cssclass="loading" ID="pnlLaden" runat="server">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle1"></div>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And place the triggers by code behind *(C#)*:

```
updCategorieen.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() {
    ControlID = rbtCat.ID,
    EventName = "CheckedChanged"
});
```

For show the loading animation I use javascript. The code below:

```
var topic = []; //--> location for all the radio buttons
var laden; //--> location for loading div

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    init();
});

function init() {

    laden = document.getElementsByClassName("loading")[0];
    topic = document.getElementsByClassName("topic");

    laden.style.display = "none";

    for (i = 0; i < topic.length; i++) {

        topic[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            startLaden();
        });
    }

    geladen.addEventListener("change", function () {
        stopLaden();
    });
}

function startLaden() {

    laden.style.display = "block";
}

function stopLaden() {

    laden.style.display = "none";

    topic = document.getElementsByClassName("topic");
}
```

**Update 2:** I've also try to remove it on server side after loading all topics.

```
pnlLaden.Style["display"] = "none";
```

That works, but if I'll show it again, the loading animations don't come back. So, I do this on the begin.

```
pnlLaden.Style["display"] = "block";
```

But has no effect...

**I've also tried** some thing found on internet but doesn't work like `live`, `on` etc. but nothing works.

Can anyone help me, I'm new with ajax and Asp.net?
Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: This has been answered hundreds of times, here's one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761713/jquery-ajax-loading-image

Comment: Have you tried the ASP.NET AJAX Control toolkit's `UpdateProgress` control? Documentation located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx).

Comment: how about using jquery's [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and its powerful ajax handlers. [$.ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) might be helpful.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: Great, it work fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Karl Anderson suggested me a to use an `asp:UpdateProgress` and it works. My code is now this:

```
<%-- my asp:UpdatePanel--%>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updPrgLadenTopics" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updPnlCategorieen" 
                    runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Panel CssClass="loading" ID="pnlLaden" runat="server">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle1"></div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```