# Show progress image while finishing my $.ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code :

```
data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'systems/createpostsystem.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    window.location = "myposts.php";
});
```

I have used `$.ajaxStart()` and it didn't do what I want.

Also I tried `success:function(){my code}` and made my request twice !

Now I want to show a progress image while this AJax complete.

Comment: What have  you tried?..

Comment: just edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Ajax Loading image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761713/jquery-ajax-loading-image)

Comment: Just show your "loading image" when you call your AJAX and hide it on ".done()". An easy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your loading image (I'm assuming a gif) before executing your ajax function. On success, remove the image and replace it with whatever you desire (success image, data returned from server, etc).

Example:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
var imageContainer = $('#selector');
imageContainer.attr('src', 'path/to/loading.gif');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'systems/createpostsystem.php',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[dom](/questions/tagged/dom)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit the DOM before doing the AJAX request, adding your loader, and then to remove it in the `complete` callback. I usually use the jQuery callback functions rather than the XHR object callbacks.

Mind that:

- the `success` callback (and the `done` XHR callback) is called only when the request completes successfully
- the `complete` (and the `always` XHR callback) is called always, even if the request fails.

Example:

```
function addLoader() {
    var img = $('<img />', { 
      id: 'loader',
      src: '/path/to/your/loader.gif'
    });
    img.appendTo($('body'));
}
function removeLoader() {
    $('#loader').remove();
}

addLoader(); // here the we add our loader
data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'systems/createpostsystem.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    complete: function() {
        removeLoader(); // here we remove it
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        window.location = "myposts.php";
    }
});
```