# jQuery Ajax loader before page loads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know if this can be achieved but I'm aking because I find this kind of page transition on many websites. My questions are 2 and the following

Is that possible to make appear a loader (gif) before html is loaded and during   a page transition?

And if yes,

Is that possible doing it through jQuery, AJAX and PHP?

I mean, I know how to implement a loader on page load like:

```
<div class="loader"><!-- whatever animated gif--></div>
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
      $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
   })
</script>
```

But at this way, I see before a white screen, then loader and next the full page. My question is about displaying a loader before the page is changing and loading, like:

1. Click on link;
2. Bam: Loader displayed;
3. Bam: page changes and loads in background.
4. Loader disappears.

Different by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761713/jquery-ajax-loading-image) which is referring to AJAX calls. I'm talking about html or php whatever page.

Comment: You can try to display load indicator as first in html and just after call `<?php flush(); ?>` http://php.net/manual/pl/function.flush.php

Comment: @jcubic thanks for your reply! Could you provide an answer to make me understand better?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [flush php function](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.flush.php) just after your ajax indicator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="loader"><!-- whatever animated gif--></div>
<?php flush(); ?>
rest of the html
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But still I see a kind of delay between clicking and seeing the loader. I'll probably go for something which is triggered by <a> click and exluding all the <a> without href value like href="#". Thanks anyway!

Comment: If the link is on your site, then you can use ajax to load the page.

Comment: Yes but I should re-think all my architecture, I guess. I've tried how I've told you and it looks pretty good. Have a great day