# Show loading image while ajax being executed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a ajax loading image to a div container while the ajax request would be executed.

My Jquery code looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#store, #gender, #username").change(function () {
            var store = $("#store").val();
            var gender = $("#gender").val();
            var receiver = $("#username").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "store" : store,
                    "gender" : gender,
                    "receiver" : receiver
                },
                url: "handling/ajax/store_items_ajax.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How would I add a loading image to the following html div:

```
<div id="result" class="col-md-12"></div>
```

Does anyone know this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Ajax Loading image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761713/jquery-ajax-loading-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Logic

```
- Create progress div element
<div id="progress">
    <img style="width:100%" src="/images/spinner.gif"/>
</div>

- By default hide this progress div
- Show when passing ajax request
- Hide when you get ajax response
```

## Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#store, #gender, #username").change(function () {
        var store = $("#store").val();
        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        var receiver = $("#username").val();

        $('#progress').show(); //show progress bar

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              "store" : store,
              "gender" : gender,
              "receiver" : receiver
            },
            url: "handling/ajax/store_items_ajax.php",
            success: function(data){
              $('#progress').hide(); //hide progress bar
              $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
      });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: i would hide the div on the complete event instead of succes.

Comment: Whichever way you need but this is robust, i have implemented this in live site and works like a charm! Please understand if you put outside then DOM will execute directly without waiting for it so may be better around AJAX request/response. Anyhow, you can play around it because you have a solution now.

Comment: you could also setup a global .ajaxStart() and save some extra lines in each of your calls.
https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/